# How to calculate x/y rotation from corner points?

Tags: flutter, math, matrix, geometry, transform

I am using the camera of a mobile phone to get a stream of images, and then analyze the images to find QR codes in them (using Googles ML Kit). Once a QR code has been found, I get the four corner-points  of the QR code in the image. I want to overlay this with a rectangle with content in it ("Container" with children in Flutter).

However, usually the camera isn't aligned perfectly to the QR code, so the corner points don't form a rectangle. So in order to overlay the QR code with my rectangle, I need to transform my rectangle so it fits to the corner points.

My question is, given the four corner points, how do I find out the transformation matrix that I need to apply to my content?

Comment: Take two closer corners (to exclude diagonal) and get angle of corresponding segment using, for example, `atan2` function. Also note that square might be non-perfect due to perspective distortions, so in general case you need to calculate matrix of perspective projection to compensate them.

Comment: yeah, that is why I need the x _and_ y rotation I believe?

Comment: if you have those 4 corner coords, why don't you simply use `CustomPaint` with `Canvas.drawPoints` / `drawPath` ?

Comment: Because I don't want to draw points, but overlay the area between the four points with a container, and for that I need to tramsform the container.

Comment: Perhaps your libraries have function for calculating and restoring perspective dist. like this (OpenCV) https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/opencv-perspective-transformation-9edffefb2143

Comment: Yes it will have more widgets in it.

Comment: so I'm afraid you need some complex math like polytopoly: https://github.com/google/skia/blob/main/src/core/SkMatrix.cpp#L1345 - you would need to port it to dart

Comment: @Christian A flat square visible through a camera doesn’t result in a rotated rectangle. Due to the perspective, it results in an irregular convex quadrilateral. You can probably render that shape on top of your QR code with Canvas.drawPath method, see there https://www.raywenderlich.com/26483389-flutter-canvas-api-getting-started

Comment: @Soonts seems that OP needs a matrix as he wants to add some other (perspective transformed) widgets inside

Comment: ok, I see now, how it's not only rotations I need to apply. I edited the question accordingly

Comment: ok so it seems i made a simple port: https://gist.github.com/pskink/e91288efc59552ae16cc2bc9e57d19cb - for params refer to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix#setPolyToPoly(float[],%20int,%20float[],%20int,%20int) - in dart they are simplified to two `List`s, each of 4 `Offset`s

Comment: @pskink wow, thank your very much, works like a charm =) If you make an answer with that, I could mark it as "accepted"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a quick port of skia's `SkMatrix::setPolyToPoly` method:

```
Matrix4? setPolyToPoly(List<Offset> src, List<Offset> dst) {
  assert(src.length == 4 && dst.length == 4);

  Matrix4? srcMatrix = _poly4Proc(src);
  if (srcMatrix == null) {
    return null;
  }

  Matrix4? dstMatrix = _poly4Proc(dst);
  if (dstMatrix == null) {
    return null;
  }

  return dstMatrix * Matrix4.inverted(srcMatrix);
}

Matrix4? _poly4Proc(List<Offset> src) {
  double a1, a2;
  double x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2;

  x0 = src[2].dx - src[0].dx;
  y0 = src[2].dy - src[0].dy;
  x1 = src[2].dx - src[1].dx;
  y1 = src[2].dy - src[1].dy;
  x2 = src[2].dx - src[3].dx;
  y2 = src[2].dy - src[3].dy;

  /* check if abs(x2) > abs(y2) */
  if ( x2 > 0 ? y2 > 0 ? x2 > y2 : x2 > -y2 : y2 > 0 ? -x2 > y2 : x2 < y2) {
    double denom = _ieeeFloatDivide(x1 * y2, x2) - y1;
    if (_checkForZero(denom)) {
      return null;
    }
    a1 = (((x0 - x1) * y2 / x2) - y0 + y1) / denom;
  } else {
    double denom = x1 - _ieeeFloatDivide(y1 * x2, y2);
    if (_checkForZero(denom)) {
      return null;
    }
    a1 = (x0 - x1 - _ieeeFloatDivide((y0 - y1) * x2, y2)) / denom;
  }

  /* check if abs(x1) > abs(y1) */
  if ( x1 > 0 ? y1 > 0 ? x1 > y1 : x1 > -y1 : y1 > 0 ? -x1 > y1 : x1 < y1) {
    double denom = y2 - _ieeeFloatDivide(x2 * y1, x1);
    if (_checkForZero(denom)) {
      return null;
    }
    a2 = (y0 - y2 - _ieeeFloatDivide((x0 - x2) * y1, x1)) / denom;
  } else {
    double denom = _ieeeFloatDivide(y2 * x1, y1) - x2;
    if (_checkForZero(denom)) {
      return null;
    }
    a2 = (_ieeeFloatDivide((y0 - y2) * x1, y1) - x0 + x2) / denom;
  }

  return Matrix4(
    a2 * src[3].dx + src[3].dx - src[0].dx, a2 * src[3].dy + src[3].dy - src[0].dy, 0, a2,
    a1 * src[1].dx + src[1].dx - src[0].dx, a1 * src[1].dy + src[1].dy - src[0].dy, 0, a1,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    src[0].dx, src[0].dy, 0, 1,
  );
}

double _ieeeFloatDivide(double d0, double d1) => d0 / d1;

bool _checkForZero(double d) => d * d == 0;
```

sample test widget:

```
class FooPerspective extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<FooPerspective> createState() => _FooPerspectiveState();
}

class _FooPerspectiveState extends State<FooPerspective> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  static const src = [
    Offset(0, 0),
    Offset(100, 0),
    Offset(100, 100),
    Offset(0, 100),
  ];
  static const dst = [
    Offset(100, 200),
    Offset(200, 220),
    Offset(220, 290),
    Offset(120, 300),
  ];

  late final ctrl = AnimationController(
    vsync: this,
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 600),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox.expand(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: ctrl,
            builder: (ctx, child) {
              final transformedDst = <Offset>[
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                  Offset.lerp(src[i], dst[i], ctrl.value)!,
              ];
              return Transform(
                transform: setPolyToPoly(src, transformedDst) ?? Matrix4.identity(),
                child: child,
              );
            },
            child: Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.orange,
                boxShadow: [BoxShadow(spreadRadius: 1, blurRadius: 6, offset: Offset(3, 3))],
              ),
              child: const Text('Cillum non minim officia excepteur in qui.', textScaleFactor: 1.2),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                ctrl.value < 0.5? ctrl.forward() : ctrl.reverse();
              },
              child: Text('start transition'),
            ),
          ),
          ...dst.map((o) => Positioned(
            left: o.dx - 8,
            top: o.dy - 8,
            width: 16,
            height: 16,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(width: 1),
              ),
            ),
          )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the result:

[image]